# Throwing an AJAX error that jQuery can catch

Tags: jquery

Using `jquery.ajax()` there are events such as "success" and "error" get triggered.

It appears as though the "error" is only triggered if some error occurs within the JavaScript function that is calling `ajax()`, rather than being based on some error coming back from the HTTP call.

I would like to do one action on success and another if some error happens within my server side processing.

What is the/is there an accepted practice of passing back a success or failure such that your client-side JS can display an error or success message?

@jason - so your code looks something like this....

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html", 
    cache: false,  
    url: "ajax_post_action.php",
    success: function(data){            
        if( response.success ) { 
            ...do something... 
        } else {
            ...tell user thre was a problem...
        }          
    },
    error: function(data){                  
        ...tell user thre was a problem...
    }   
    });
```

Comment: Pass a 500 back in case of error. That should make it trigger the error callback.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1. You can have your response from the server contain the success or failure information.  Then have your ajax `success` function check the response's value and handle it appropriately.

   We use this approach.  Our response is a JSON object that at a minimum contains:
   `{ success: <bool>, errorMessage: <string> }`
   Then our ajax `success` function can simply check `if(response.success) { ... }`
2. You can have your service write out the HTTP status to an error code with a specific message.  Then your ajax `error` function can process it.

Comment: Since `success: function(data)` is passing in `data` as the variable, you'd want to change it to `if(data.success){...}`, but other than that, yes!  That is how we handle it.